# mount an external usb hdd and share through samba

Tags: systemd, mount, samba, fstab

I have an external usb hdd. I would like to do this: automount it from boot and share it through samba.

1) I put it in the fstab and it automounts correctly on boot, no problem:

```
UUID=XXX /usb-hdd ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
```

2) share /usb-hdd through samba after it was mounted. No problem.

```
[usb-hdd]
comment = raid5-usb
path = /usb-hdd
read only = No
valid users = michaelm
```

3) however, if the machine restarts, the samba share will fail. It can easily be solved by

```
systemctl restart smbd
```

4) for your reference, the "systemctl status smbd" returns following message on boot:

```
May 06 14:44:37 storage systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
May 06 14:44:38 storage systemd[1]: smbd.service: Supervising process 1172 which is not our child. We'll
May 06 14:46:07 storage systemd[1]: smbd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 06 14:47:38 storage systemd[1]: smbd.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
May 06 14:47:38 storage systemd[1]: smbd.service: Killing process 1172 (smbd) with signal SIGKILL.
May 06 14:47:38 storage systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
May 06 14:47:38 storage systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 06 14:47:38 storage systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

My guess is that on boot, smbd service starts before /usb-hdd is mounted. How to correct it?

Comment: can you add the samba config of the share ?

Comment: added (from smb.conf file). samba share works well. I can reach it from other machines.

Comment: also added the error message for your reference. thanks.